# Web scraping using Multiprocessing in python: selenium versus celery

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, celery, selenium-grid

Would multiprocessing with Selenium Grid be the same as doing Celery in web scraping?

2) What would be the most correct and efficient approach?

3) Taking into account that you want to include docker in the solution set?